# Don't know how to form a short question so any help would be appreciated

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I made this poll command that people without admin could make polls. To prevent spam, there is a verify step for everyone without admin. But when you react to the poll to verify it, it only works for the person making the poll. And not the admin that's supposed to check if it's not spam.

So when the admin reacts nothing happens but when the person that made the poll reacts to it, it verifies the poll and sends it to the main channel.

Code is down below is someone could help! 'Appreciate it!

```js
 const {Client, Collection, GuildMember, User, MessageEmbed, Message} = require("discord.js");
    const ms = require("ms");
    const delay = (msec) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, msec));
    module.exports.run = async(client, message, args, user, reaction) => {
    
        var woord = '!poll' 
        var question = args.slice(0).join(' ') 
        var poll = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${message.author.username} wil een poll maken.`)
            .setDescription(question)
            .setColor('#eb8dd8')
            .setFooter(`Poll gemaakt door: `+ message.author.username)
    
        var success = new MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(question)
            .setColor('#eb8dd8')
            .setFooter("Poll started door: "+ message.author.username)
    
            
    
        if(message.content.includes(woord)) {
            message.delete({timeout:0}) 
        }
    
        if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === 'Barman')) {
            if(message.channel.name.includes("-poll")) {
                if(args[0]) {
                    message.delete()
                    message.guild.channels.create(message.author.username, { permissionOverwrites:[
                        {
                            deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                            id: message.guild.id
                        },
                        {
                            allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                            id: message.author.id
                        },
                    ],
                }).then(channel => {
                    channel.send(poll).then(poll => {
                        poll.react('✅')
                        .then(() => poll.react('❌'));
                    })
                })
    
                } else {
                    message.delete()
                }
            }
        } else {
            var pollChannel = client.channels.cache.get('876531134702448701')
            pollChannel.send(success).then(success => {
                success.react('✅')
                .then(() => success.react('❌'))
            })
        }
        
    
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
            const deleteChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === user.username);
            var pollChannel = client.channels.cache.get('876531134702448701')
            if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
                if(message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === user.username)) {
                    deleteChannel.delete()
                    .then(channel => {
                        pollChannel.send(success).then(success =>{
                            success.react('✅')
                            .then(() => success.react('❌'))
                        })
                    })
                    
    
                }
            } if(reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
                if(message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === user.username)) {
                    deleteChannel.delete()
                }
            }
        })
    }
        
    
    
    module.exports.help = {
        name: "poll"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your function you can do this:

```js
const questions = new Collection();
questions.set("What is the color of healthy grass?", "green");
questions.set("How many vowels are there in these letters: apple", "2");
const chosen = questions.randomKey()
await message.channel.send(`Please answer the question. This is to prevent spam. Make sure your spelling is correct. You have 30 seconds —> ${chosen}`)
try {
  await message.channel.awaitMessages((m) => m.author.id === message.author.id && m.content.toLowerCase() === questions.get(chosen), {
    time: 30000, 
    max: 1
  })
} catch(err) { 
  return message.channel.send("You ran out of time to answer correctly!")
}
//code to make poll
```

Your `awaitMessages` syntax may be different on v13. You can also replace my questions, and add as many as you want!